# Does Mongo DB have functions similar to Oracle triggers

Tags: mongodb, triggers

Dose mongo has some functions similar to oracle trigger? When i insert a document it can automatic update the fields createdTimestamp and modifiedTimestamp.

**Excample:**

After inserting/updating data:

```
{
'name': 'bobo',
'age': 17
}
```

final data will be updated as below. It means trigger dose time fields updating for me.

```
{
'name': 'bobo',
'age': 17,
'createdTimestamp': 2020-09-17T09:31:14.416+00:00,
'modifiedTimestamp': 2020-09-17T09:31:14.440+00:00
}
```

My solution is to use `$currentDate` and `$setOnInsert`, to update set `upsert=true`, code as below:

```
created_modified_timestamp_operation = {
    '$currentDate': {
        modifiedTimestamp: true
    },
    '$setOnInsert': {
        createdTimestamp: new Date()
    }
}
```

But for this solution I need to modify a lot of data operations，so I want to know is there any functions is similar to Oracle trigger, i just need to write a trigger to monitor whether the database is modified.

Thanks~~

Comment: [ChangeStreams](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/changeStreams/index.html) (Change streams are available for replica sets and sharded clusters).

Comment: According to the document, it is works on replica sets or sharded clusters, but in my development environment,  we does not created replica sets or sharded clusters, so I need another way to solve this problem, am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

Well triggers are only available in MongoDB atlas. But you can create triggers if you are using something like `mongoose` since it supports creating pre/post save, update triggers which I believe though are application level but can be of great help. And yes there are `Change Streams` you can read about them as well.